# Is there a way to LOG RC Selenium test errors/failures into a database?

Tags: mysql, selenium, phpunit, phpundercontrol

Im using phpunit & phpundercontrol to run the RC Selenium on every build.

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit allows you to implement your own **TestListener**. Custom test listeners implement the abstract methods in the **PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener** interface. Specifically, your listener will implement:

- startTestSuite()
- endTestSuite()
- startTest()
- endTest()
- addError()
- addFailure()
- addSkippedTest()
- addIncompleteTest()

Once you've attached the TestListner these methods will be called each time the corresponding events occur in your test suite. These methods will be written to perform the *INSERTs* and *UPDATEs* on a test results database that you'll create.

Attaching the listener class to your suite is as easy as adding a  tag to the **phpunit.xml** configuration file. For example:

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>[...]</testsuites>
  <selenium>[...]</selenium>
  <listeners>
    <listener class="Database" 
              file="/usr/loocal/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Log/Database.php">
  </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

That's all you need!

In fact, PHPUnit already comes with a working version of the listener I just described (**PHPUnit_Util_Log_Database**), as well as two different database schema definitions.

On many systems this class will live at **/usr/loocal/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Log/Database.php**, and the schemas at **/usr/loocal/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Log/Database/MySQL.sql** and **/usr/loocal/share/pear/PHPUnit/Util/Log/Database/SQLite3.sql**. You may have to do some tweaking depending on the DBMS you're using.

---

See these sections of the documentation (it wont let me post two links:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener

htp://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/api.html#api.testresult.tables.testlistener

(StackOverflow won't let me post two links, so you'll have to correct the HTTP in that second one)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem.

Have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117714/perl-tap-testing-how-to-get-count-of-failed-tests-from-tapformatterhtml-outp) a few days ago.

My attempt using Selenium IDE, Selenium RC and perl.

*General strategy:*

You can make newer releases of phpunit generate TAP output (options --tap, --log-tap).

(TAP is Test Anything Protocol - standardized output format)

Parse the logfile to obtain the suite metadata from the TAP parser object, insert into database using perl, e.g. "# Number of Passed": , "Failed", "Unexpectedly succeeded",